# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') and ensure

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I have this problem when working on old project here's the code for the get and ensure one, I'm using djs 13 currently

```
  client.Jobremind = new CronJob("*/5 * * * * *", async function(){
    let data = client.afkDB.get("REMIND")
    if(!data) {
        client.afkDB.ensure("REMIND", {
            REMIND: []
        });
        data = [];
    }
    var reminds_now = data.REMIND.filter(v=>{
        return v.time - (Date.now() - v.timestamp) <= 0
    })
```

picture below the code is the error

[image: And here's the error]

Appreciate those who can help and thanks for your time for reading this.

Comment: It is saying that it can’t find a value for client.afkDB, take a look at the code around where you have a line starting `client.afkDB = `

Comment: Side note, cronjobs only have the following elements for time `(min hr dayOfMonth month dayOfWeek)` => `(‘* * * * *’)` you have a sixth one there that does nothing